# Drivers not installing and drives not being recognized

Tags: windows-7, drivers, external-hard-drive, pci

Dell optiplex 755 running win7-32

Two problems, not sure if they're related

1: Two drivers are missing when viewing device manager, PCI serial port and PCI Simple Communications Controller, I've searched dell's site, and the internet as a whole and have been wholly unable to find the drivers.

2: I'm unable to connect any external hard drives, but any flash drives plugged in will be recognized and accessible by the computer without issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

hmm did the dell site list the computer as win7 compatible? does it have non oem  part in it?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding drivers, did you try this site:

[Dell Optiplex drivers](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/index.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs)

And then, regarding the external hard drives.  How are these connected?  USB, Firewire?  If you are missing some drivers, it's possible this is causing your external drives to not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Windows 7 not recognizing an external hard drive. I uninstalled all of the USB Root Hub devices in Device Manager, rebooted the machine, let Windows reinstall the USB Root Hubs and then the external hard drive was recognized.